# Puedo hacer que mi personaje aparezca en una ubicación no definida?

Tags: pygame

Soy nuevo en esto así que si es una pregunta tonta disculpen mi ignorancia, estoy intentando crear un juego de plataforma en el cual la ubicación de la plataforma inicial sea aleatoria, pero que a su vez el personaje aparezca siempre sobre la plataforma, no sé si tengo que crear algún otro argumento para la clase de la plataforma o debo crear otra función que sirva para generar al jugador exclusivamente o hay alguna otra manera, agradecería sus consejos

Comment: Hola, no sabemos nada sobre tu juego, ni qué librería estás usando ni nada en absoluto sobre tu problema. Así que te recomiendo, primero que nada, que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes agregar el código de lo que intentaste hasta el momento, de lo contrario no podemos ayudarte porque no sabemos que intentaste.

Comment: Podrías crear una posición de inicialización que fuera aleatoria y tanto el personaje como la plataforma que tengan posición relativa con respecto a la posición de incialización. Por cierto, al ser una pregunta basada en opiniones es probable que termine cerrada, si tienes código que no funcione agregalo junto con los errores para poder ayudarte.